# socket.io: disconnect event isn't fired

Tags: node.js, events, socket.io, disconnect

I have made a simple realtime visitor counter.

You can download it from [this repository](https://bitbucket.org/bitliner/nodejs-mycounter).

What happens is that disconnect event (even after browser closing) on server is never fired.

server.js is:

```
(function () {
var app, count, express, io;

express = require('express');
io = require('socket.io');

app = module.exports = express.createServer();

app.configure(function () {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(require('stylus').middleware({
        src: __dirname + '/public'
    }));
    app.use(app.router);
    return app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function () {
    return app.use(express.errorHandler({
        dumpExceptions: true,
        showStack: true
    }));
});
app.configure('production', function () {
    return app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

count = 0;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    count++;
    io.sockets.emit('count', {
        number: count
    });
});

io.sockets.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('DISCONNESSO!!! ');
    count--;
    io.sockets.emit('count', {
        number: count
    });
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    return res.render('index', {
        title: 'node.js express socket.io counter'
    });
});
if (!module.parent) {
    app.listen(10927);
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d", app.address().port);
}

}).call(this);
```

Script on the client is:

```
    script(type='text/javascript')

        var socket = io.connect();

        socket.on('count', function (data) {
            $('#count').html( data.number );
        });
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Put your on disconnect code inside your on connect block and edit it a bit like so:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    count++;
    io.sockets.emit('count', {
        number: count
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('DISCONNESSO!!! ');
        count--;
        io.sockets.emit('count', {
            number: count
        });
    });
});
```

This way you're detecting when a specific socket (specifically the socket you pass to your anonymous function that is run on connection) is disconnected.

Comment: Did you notice that I have written socket.on above?

Comment: FYI, if xhr-polling is being used for the transport, there may be quite a delay before the disconnect.

Comment: Does XHR-Polling also affect connect events?

Comment: As @NoNameProvided mentioned, the disconnect event should use `once` instead of `on`

Answer (score 3):

**From Socket.IO 1.0** the `io.engine.clientsCount` property is available. This property tells you how many open connection does your app currently have.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    io.sockets.emit('count', {
        number: io.engine.clientsCount
    });

    socket.once('disconnect', function () {
        io.sockets.emit('count', {
            number: io.engine.clientsCount
        });
    });
});
```

Note: Use `.once` instead of `.on` and the listener will be removed automatically from the `socket` what is good for us now, because the disconnect event is only fired once per socket.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone else made this silly mistake: make sure that any socket middleware you've defined calls `next()` at the end, or else no other socket handlers will run.

```js
// make sure to call next() at the end or...
io.use(function (socket, next) {
    console.log(socket.id, "connection middleware");
    next(); // don't forget this!
});

// ...none of the following will run:

io.use(function (socket, next) {
    console.log(socket.id, "second middleware");
    next(); // don't forget this either!
});

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.id, "connection event");
    socket.once("disconnect", function () {
        console.log(socket.id, "disconnected");
    });
});
```

Comment: This next() really took me hours to find. It what I needed to preform action right after a socket disconnects. Should be more visible this.