# Persisting websocket connection with socket.io

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, websocket, socket.io

There is a server ([mtgox websockets](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/Streaming) for anyone interested) that I'm trying to collect data from. The trouble I'm having is that sometimes I connect and I begin receiving data from the server and other times I connect and nothing happens. The connection event is fired in both instances. I have no idea why this happens. It does not depend on the code and whether it works or not seems totally random.

To over come this I decided to persist my socket connection. If data does not begin to flow in a couple seconds then I would like to try connecting again. This should repeat until a true connection is established.

```
events = require 'events'
io = require 'socket.io-client'
colors = require 'colors'

module.exports = class Mtgox extends events.EventEmitter

    constructor: () ->

        @socket = io.connect('https://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox')
        @connected = false
        # establish connection
        @connect()

        @socket.on('connect', () =>
            console.log "connected"
            @socket.on('message', (message) =>
                console.log "in on message"
                @connection = true
                @emit(message.private, message[message.private])
            )
        )

    connect: ->

        @connected = false

        id = setInterval(
            () =>   
                if not @connected
                    console.log "persisting".blue
                    # console.log @socket
                    @socket = io.connect('https://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox')
                else 
                    clearInterval(id)
        , 5000)
```

This method does not work, as when I reset `@socket` (`this.socket`) to `io.connect('https://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox')` the connection event is not fired again. How can I re-establish a socket connection if the first one fails?

---

**Note:** There does not seem to be any difference between a working socket object and a broken one (one that does not send data) but here is a broken one logged.

```
{ socket:
   { options:
      { port: 443,
        secure: true,
        document: false,
        resource: 'socket.io',
        transports: [Object],
        'connect timeout': 10000,
        'try multiple transports': true,
        reconnect: true,
        'reconnection delay': 500,
        'reconnection limit': Infinity,
        'reopen delay': 3000,
        'max reconnection attempts': 10,
        'sync disconnect on unload': false,
        'auto connect': true,
        'flash policy port': 10843,
        manualFlush: false,
        host: 'socketio.mtgox.com',
        query: '' },
     connected: true,
     open: true,
     connecting: false,
     reconnecting: false,
     namespaces: { '/mtgox': [Circular], '': [Object] },
     buffer: [],
     doBuffer: false,
     sessionid: 'ZwxMQD749XUTdgnb1yWu',
     closeTimeout: 60000,
     heartbeatTimeout: 60000,
     origTransports: [ 'websocket' ],
     transports: [ 'websocket' ],
     heartbeatTimeoutTimer:
      { _idleTimeout: 60000,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _idleStart: Sun Sep 01 2013 15:08:47 GMT-0400 (EDT) },
     transport:
      { socket: [Circular],
        sessid: 'ZwxMQD749XUTdgnb1yWu',
        websocket: [Object],
        isOpen: true,
        closeTimeout: [Object] },
     connectTimeoutTimer:
      { _idleTimeout: -1,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleNext: null,
        _onTimeout: null,
        _idleStart: Sun Sep 01 2013 15:08:46 GMT-0400 (EDT),
        ontimeout: null },
     '$events': {} },
  name: '/mtgox',
  flags: {},
  json: { namespace: [Circular], name: 'json' },
  ackPackets: 0,
  acks: {},
  '$events':
   { connect: [Function],
     disconnect: [Function],
     error: [Function],
     message: [Function] } }
```

Comment: Have you looked at disconnect? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342548/socket-io-disconnect-event-isnt-fired/10342610#10342610

Comment: @jcollum I tried that and it worked but then when I reconnected, and by that I mean called `@socket = io.connect('https://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox')` the connection event was never fired again. Though I would then disconnect again and disconnect would fire.